# Somewhat-hardware-conscious algorithm for top k-of-n with $k=\Omega(\sqrt{n})$

Tags: algorithms, searching, filtering-problem

The "top k of n" problem: You have n (not necessarily distinct) elements in an array, and you need to return another array containing the k elements with the highest value.

So, I'm going to need a top-k-of-n implementation for something I'm working on. Never mind exactly which programming language and hardware I'm going to use - but do mind that it's going to actually run on actual hardware. Thus there is multi-level caching so dereferencing pointers to arbitrary places should be minimized; there's the balance between computation and memory bandwidth to consider; there's multithreads/SIMDizing/whatever so I would like something parallelizable without too much communication... that's what I meant by somewhat-hardware-conscious.

Anyway, for a really small k I would probably just use a priority queue which fits in cache (or even linear search through several registers). But - what if your k is large? Large that the top k elements won't just be hiding at the top end of an estimated distribution? In this case I was thinking of estimating k using sampling, then (sort of) partitioning on that guess k; seeing how badly I missed; and iterating that, either partitioning my more-than-k or my more-than-n-minus-k. On one hand the length decreases quickly, and on the other hand I get closer to the really-small-k case, until I can settle for a priority queue (say for each core even) for the last bit.

So, my questions are:

- Can someone describe known algorithms for this variant of the problem,  meeting my "vague hardware consciousness" constraint?
- Does the algorithm sketch I described sound like something you know?
- If not, does it sound like a good idea or can you describe shortcomings of this kind of an approach?

**Notes:**

- You may assume the data are non-negative integers if it helps in any way (I don't think it should), or make any any other reasonable assumptions.
- This problem is different that the [partial sorting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting) in that the output does not need to be sorted. Of course, for small k = $o(\sqrt{n})$ there isn't that much of a difference.
- The data is in memory, i.e. this is not a streaming algorithm and you can read data multiple times. You can't alter the input; you can make a full copy but hopefully that should be overkill.

Comment: Your idea is similar to Quickselect.

Comment: Idea: Split your data into cache-sized parts. Solve the problem on these parts in parallel. Proceed similarly with all the top $k$ elements you find until only $k$ elements are left.

Comment: @Raphael: That can only work if k is significantly smaller than the relevant cache size, which is not necessarily the case (and not practically, for me).

Comment: @Raphael: Also, even when that can be used, it's still quite wasteful. Why? Suppose the data is $\{1...n\}$ and k is exactly $\sqrt{n}$ I can establish using just a bit of sampling that the k'th highest value is over $n-2\sqrt{n}$; now I can completely ignore all elements below that when I read the input. Although of course I could take your approach after doing the estimate.

Comment: You said in the question that $k = \Theta(\sqrt{n})$, so that example isn't relevant here.  $k = (1 - 1/1000) n$ doesn't satisfy $k = \Theta(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Ok, I'm going to do something a bit ugly, but which doesn't invalidate anybody's answer. I'm making it $\Omega(\sqrt{n})$. But I'll still correct the example.

Comment: If you want us to focus on the case where $k$ is larger than the cache size, it'd help to state that in the question (and clarify the model a bit more if you can -- is this a hardware circuit?  parallel processing with multiple processors?  does each processor have access to large sequential-access memory and a small random-access cache?).

Comment: @D.W.: It's actually a GPU, but I didn't want to be that specific.

Comment: I think you'll get better answers if you are specific.  Otherwise, you're forcing us to guess your requirements.  You can still edit to clarify the relevant properties of the GPU (along the lines I sketched), without having to say it's for a GPU.  Also, given your edit, please confirm whether we can assume $k \le n/2$. (If not, the first step may well be to set $k' = n-k$ and then find the $k'$th smallest element, which is equivalent to finding the $k$th largest element.  Tell us in the question whether we have to deal with this corner case explicitly, or if we can assume $k \le n/2$.)

Comment: @D.W.: Of course k <= n/2 ... the assumption about k is that it's not very small, since for the very-small-k case we can work in cache, we can use min-heaps, and in general it all seems kind of easy. I chose $\sqrt{n}$ for "significantly large". I will edit the answer as you suggest, but it'll be tomorrow probably since it's getting late. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: OK.  You previously gave an example where $k=0.999n$, which is why I'm checking things that might seem obvious to you.   As far as your edited comment about using sampling: no, you can't conclude that the $k$th highest value is over $n-2\sqrt{n}$, as that will depend on the specific values in the array.  (For example, what if all of the elements of the array are 1?)  Sampling can be useful, but it's a bit trickier than that.  Are you assuming that array elements are uniformly distributed on $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and wondering about average-case/expected running time, maybe?

Comment: If staying in cache is *that* important (have you done any benchmarks yet?) you can use my approach and find the $\min(k,C)$ ($C$ the cache size) smallest items. Repeat on the rest until you have selected $k$ elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to make multiple passes through the data, one efficient approach is to use [QuickSelect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) to find the value of the $k$-th largest element, then follow with a linear scan that outputs all elements that are larger than it.

This is more or less a more carefully-worked out version of the kind of approach you seemed to be considering.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm.

---

The following approach was written for an earlier version of the question, which specified $k = O(\sqrt{n})$, but might not be useful for large $k$:

Another possible approach would be to take a [sorting network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network), which is a hardware circuit that sorts all of the values.  Then, throw away all but the last $k$ outputs, and keep only the gates they depend on.  You might be able to throw away a non-trivial fraction of the sorting network -- I haven't tried to work out how much.  This would solve the partial sorting network, and could potentially be hardware-friendly.

---

The following approach was written for an earlier version of the question, which specified $k = O(\sqrt{n})$, but might not be useful for large $k$:

Another approach is to do something like merge sort, but where you only keep the top $k$ elements in each list at each stage.  In other words, split your data so that each processor receives an equal number of items.  Have each processor find the top $k$ of its elements (say, using a priority queue or any other method).  Then merge lists recursively, where each merge operation merges two or more lists of size $k$ and outputs only the first (largest) $k$ elements of the result.  This might work very well for out-of-cache (too-large-to-fit-in-main-memory) situations, or for parallel computing.  If you can fit $B$ items in cache/memory, then each merge step merges $B/k$ lists, so the number of rounds is $\lg_{B/k} (n/B)$.

Comment: You want me to repeatedly pivot all of my data? :-(  I know about QuickSelect, of course, but while it's theoretically nifty, I'm sure you can do much better in practice. And when I say better, I mean the constants in the O(...) notation. My suggestion, assuming it's valid, should give  (1+o(1)) expected passes + f(k) complexity afterwards.

Comment: @einpoklum "I'm sure you can do much better in practice" -- not for selection, you can't. And you clearly *do* have to solve selection (with parameter $k$) as a subproblem, so I think D.W.'s answer may be very good. Incidentally, Quickselect is also quite tame w.r.t. caching.

Comment: Median of medians is cache-oblivious; I assume Quickselect is as well.  Partitioning is a side effect of the algorithm.

Comment: The hardware is not nearly big enough to have a size-n network. Think of n as being less than an order of magnitude below the size of RAM.